# How to get Facebook access token of the current PFUser

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I need to get the Facebook access token of the current user who is logged in using Facebook so that i can send it to a web service to be able to call Facebook Graph APIs

So How do I get the auth data from the [PFUser currentUser]? as I've tried the following but it returns nil:

```
PFObject *authData = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"authData"];
```

Comment: Try preceding `authData` with an underscore, i.e., `_authData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the access token from PFFacebookUtils as the following

```
NSString *accessToken = [[[PFFacebookUtils session] accessTokenData] accessToken];
```

Comment: I got error "PFFacebookUtils has no member session" after adding this line

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I had the same problem and PFFacebookUtils don't have a session property anymore, but this works:

```
[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
```